# Wie nennt man die kleinen "Wachhäuschen" mit religiösem Inhalt?

Tags: single-word-request, religion

Manchmal gibt es ja zum Beispiel als Kreuzwegstation ein kleines steinernes Gebäude mit ein, zwei qm Fläche, welches dazu dient eine religiöse Abbildung einzurahmen und zu schützen. Im Osten sieht man auch oftmals solche Bauten mit Ikonen und Heiligenstatuen darin. Oft ist es auch nur ein steinernes Kreuz mit einer Aussparung für den Gegenstand.
Gibt es einen Fachbegriff für solche religiösen Kleinstgebäude, die man oft am Wegrand findet? 
Ab wann kann man von einer Kapelle sprechen?

Comment: *Heiligenhäuschen*

Comment: [Heiligenhäuschen bei Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heiligenhäuschen) hat noch weitere alternative Bezeichnungen

Comment: Im Bayrischen ein *Marterl*

Comment: Auch *Kreuzwegstation* kommt vor, nämlich dann, wenn davon mehrere entlang einer Route aufgestellt sind und ihr Inhalt die Etappen der Passion Christi darstellt.

Comment: Verrückt, für mich wären künstliche religiöse Orte immer mindestens Tempel. Da hab ich im Alter ja schön noch was gelernt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das ist eine Kapelle oder ein Bildstock, je nachdem, ob ein Altar vorhanden ist oder nicht.

### Kapelle

Wenn das Gebäude einen Altar enthält, ist es eine Kapelle. Kapellen können sehr klein sein, insbesondere ist es nicht erforderlich, dass man das Gebäude betreten kann. Es kann nämlich durchaus sein, dass in einer Kapelle für nichts außer dem Altar Platz ist, wobei auch dieser Altar so klein sein kann, dass er eigentlich nur aus einem Brett besteht, auf dem man Blumen und Kerzen unter einem Kruzifix oder Heiligenbild abstellen kann. In jedem Fall reicht aber das Dach des Gebäudes über den Altar hinaus, was aber nicht ausschließt, dass bei starkem Wind auch der Altar Regen abbekommt.

### Bildstock

Ein Bildstock hat keinen Altar. Ein Bildstock ist ist eine Art Säule, an der ein Relief oder ein Bild angebracht ist, das eine religiöse Szene darstellt. Im alpenländischen Raum ist der synonyme Begriff *»Marterl«* gängiger als *»Bildstock«*.

Answer (score 10):

Wenn das sehr kleine „Gebäude“ sind, in denen gerade einmal das Kunstwerk platz hat, kenne ich die unter dem Begriff [Bildstock, Bilderstock oder auch Heiligenstock](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bildstock), im Rheinland auch [Bilderstöckchen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilderst%C3%B6ckchen). Ein Kölner Stadtteil ist auch danach benannt. Größere Gebäude, in die einzelne Personen hineinpassen, nennt man auch *Kapellenbildstock*.